# Check Source code changed since last TFS successful build

Tags: tfs, build, build-automation

In TFS 2010 custom activity how to find out programatically whether my project(s) source code changed / checked in since its last successful build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the build and version control APIs to achieve this.

First, you need to figure out the last successful build label by looking at the [LastGoodBuildLabel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.server.builddefinition.lastgoodbuildlabel.aspx) property of your build definition.

Use this label as the versionFrom argument of the [QueryHistory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff736442.aspx) method and the Latest version spec as the versionTo, you can check to see if there is any History entry exists between there and now.

You need to specify the path as the root of your source code, set recursive to true, and other extra information flags to false. You might also want to set the maximum count of History entries to be 1 because all you need to know is whether it exists.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Duat, But in case of multiple projects how to identify which project got changed??

Comment: Hi, if you want to identify which project's source code has changed then you need to issue the query for each individual project by specifying the root of that project as the path you query on. In this case you will need to do multiple queries, one for each project.

Comment: Duat, can you help me how to iterate through the Project path as I am not able to get the project folder path required for QueryHistory. I used Approach 1: GetAllTeamProject or var projectCollection = (ICommonStructureService)tfs.GetService(typeof(ICommonStructureService)); foreach (var projectInfo in projectCollection.ListProjects()) { //do stuff here }....... But nothing is coming as the path of projects required by QueryHistory. PLease let me know how to iterate through the project paths.

Comment: I thought you meant your code projects, not TFS team projects. For the team projects, you can use this method to get all team projects and the TeamProject.ServerItem property is what you want: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.versioncontrolserver.getallteamprojects.aspx

Comment: Duat, I need the project names inside a solution and not Team Projects. I have a solution A and with that solution Project AB, AC and AD is bind. How to get the server path and local path of AB, AC & AD?

Comment: Hm you should know which projects you want to check. I think you can query the *.csproj files (if you're building C# projects) under your solution path. Another possible solution is to figure out the projects from your solution file but to be honest I haven't tried it.